# React Native - Change component style after import

Tags: react-native

sorry if this issue has been asked already, I didn't find any topics on this.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to change a component style after importing it. Let's say I created a button component that has specific style properties.

```js
const Button = () => {
 const { buttonStyle } = styles;
 return (
  <TouchableOpacity style={buttonStyle}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 buttonStyle: {
  flex: 1,
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#007aff',
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 5

 }
});

export { Button };
```

And that I want to import this button in my view like so, but I need to change the 'borderColor' or any other style property.

```js
import Button from './src/components/Button';

render() {
  return (
   <Button>
   </Button>
  );
 };
```

Is there anyway to do this? Or maybe a different approach to it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass custom style via props and override styles that are set in the Button component. This is achieved by passing an array of style objects to the 'style' prop. Example:

```js
const Button = (props) => {
    const { buttonStyle } = styles;
    const style = props.style;
  
 return (
  <TouchableOpacity style={[buttonStyle, style]}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 buttonStyle: {
  flex: 1,
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#007aff',
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 5

 }
});

export { Button };
```

```js
import Button from './src/components/Button';

render() {
  return (
   <Button style={{borderColor: 'red'}}>
   </Button>
  );
 };
```